# How to display facebook graph api json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to display facebook newsfeed data using jquery. It is working fine but there is one problem. First here is the facebook newsfeed on which I am working.

```
{
"data":
[
    {
        "id":"342432423",
        "from":
            {
                "name":"name",
                "id":"234234324"
            },
        "message": "this is message",
        "icon":"http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v27562/23/2231777543/app_2_2231777543_9553.gif",
        "actions":
            [
                {
                    "name":"Comment",
                    "link":"http://www.facebook.com/533187120/posts/10150296687547121"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Like",
                    "link":"http://www.facebook.com/533187120/posts/10150296687547121"
                },
                {
                    "name":"@name on Twitter",
                    "link":"http://twitter.com/name?utm_source=fb&utm_medium=fb&utm_campaign=Karsteinvolle&utm_content=23432423423"
                }
            ],
        "type":"status",
        "application":{"name":"Twitter","id":"2231777543"},
        "created_time":"2011-09-13T12:10:32+0000",
        "updated_time":"2011-09-13T12:10:32+0000",
        "comments":{"count":0}
    }]
```

So the problem is that I manage to display message, from, type, application, created_time etc but 
HOW CAN I DISPLAY ACTIONS?

here is my jquery code

```
$(function(){
            $.getJSON("json_data/newsfeed.json",function(d) {
                //var actions = d.data.actions;
                var html = "<ul>";
                $.each(d.data, function(i,res) {
                    //html += "<li><img src='" + res.icon + "' /></li>";
                    html += "<li>From: " + res.from.name + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>Message: " + res.message + "</li>";
                    //alert(res.actions.length);
                    //$.each(d.data.actions, function(i, act) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < res.actions.length; i++) {
                        html += "<li>Actions: " + res[i] + " " + res.actions.link + "</li>";
                    }
                        //html += "<li>Actions: " + act.name + "</li>";
                   //});
                });
                html += "</ul>";
                $("#contents").html(html);
            });
        });
```

I am confused please help me

Answer (score 0):

To parse Json, simply do as object:

```
$.each(d.data, function(i,res) {
    //[your code]
    $.each(res.actions, function(i,action) {
        // display action here 
        // action.name
        // action.link
    }
}
```